# Fallback if statement based on the number filtered from it

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop

I'm trying to add three ads on a page. I have a custom post type called 'ads' and I'm using advanced custom fields to add a start date an end date and an option to select which pages to associate them with.

I want to set a fallback image for the ads if there aren't any ads that fit within this criteria..

```
if ( $start_date <= $current_date && $end_date >= $current_date && in_array( $page_id, $page_ids ) )
```

So lets say I have 6 ads setup and only 1 fits that criteria and is still active. The `else statement` doesn't take into consideration how many ads are active, so if there is only 1 ad active it will still show 3. I would like to have it only show the fallback ads if there are zero ads that fit in that `if statement` but can't figure out how to do that at this point in the loop.

I have the `posts_per_page` set to unlimited because I need to filter them by date and pages associated with them, so I'm using `$i < 3` on the while loop to limit it to three ads from that point.

Basically don't show any fallback ads unless there are zero ads that fit the `if statement`.

This is probably more of a PHP question but it includes the wp loop so figured this would be the better place to ask. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

```
<?php
$current_date = date('Ymd');
$page_object  = get_queried_object();
$page_id      = get_queried_object_id();

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'ads',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'rand'
);

$ads = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $ads->have_posts() ) : $i = 0;
    while ( $ads->have_posts() && $i < 3 ) : $ads->the_post();
        $start_date = get_field( 'start_date' );
        $end_date   = get_field( 'end_date' );
        $link       = get_field( 'link' );
        $display    = get_field( 'display_on_page' );
        $page_ids   = array();

        // Store ID's in an array
        foreach ( $display as $post_object ) {
            $page_ids[] = $post_object->ID;
        }

        // Show ads that are inbetween start & end dates and match the page_ids selected
        if ( $start_date <= $current_date && $end_date >= $current_date && in_array( $page_id, $page_ids ) ) {
            ?>
            <div class="col-1-3">
                <div class="advertisement footer-ad">
                    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'ads' ); ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        } else {
            // Will loop 3 times for fallback ads ?>
            <div class="col-1-3">
                <div class="advertisement footer-ad">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/ad-listing.jpg" alt="Advertisement">
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
   $i++;
   endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: So, if there is no match for the first post and the default ad is displayed, you do not want the default to also show up in the second or third unmatched post? Is that correct?

Comment: The idea is that it grabs all the ads, and then it should limit those to three ads that fit inbetween the start and end dates. So I would only want it to display a fallback ad if no ads fit that criteria out of x amount of ads. Sorry it's kind of hard to explain..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some help from a friend and figured out that I needed to move the post_meta stuff into the query with meta_query then just set a fallback from there.

```
<?php
$current_date = date('Ymd');
$page_object  = get_queried_object();
$page_id      = get_queried_object_id();

// Match the string "123" to the database value a:1:{i:0;s:3:"123";} (serialized array) for ACF
$page_id      = '"' . $page_id . '"'; 

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'ads',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'start_date',
            'value'   => $current_date,
            'compare' => '<=',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'end_date',
            'value'   => $current_date,
            'compare' => '>=',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'display_on_page',
            'value'   => $page_id,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
   )
);

$ads = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $ads->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $ads->have_posts() ) : $ads->the_post();
        $link = get_field( 'link' );
        ?>
        <div class="col-1-3">
            <div class="advertisement footer-ad">
                <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'ads' ); ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
   endwhile;
else: ?>
    <div class="col-1-3">
        <div class="advertisement footer-ad">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/ad-listing.jpg" alt="Advertisement">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-3">
        <div class="advertisement footer-ad">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/ad-listing.jpg" alt="Advertisement">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-3">
        <div class="advertisement footer-ad">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/ad-listing.jpg" alt="Advertisement">
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
endif;
?>
```